# How do these stream redirections work?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

From [this perldoc page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60),

1. To capture a command's STDERR and STDOUT together:

   ```
   $output = `cmd 2>&1`;
   ```
2. To capture a command's STDOUT but discard its STDERR:

   ```
   $output = `cmd 2>/dev/null`;
   ```
3. To capture a command's STDERR but discard its STDOUT (ordering is important here):

   ```
   $output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
   ```
4. To exchange a command's STDOUT and STDERR in order to capture the STDERR but leave its STDOUT to come out the old STDERR:

   ```
   $output = `cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`;
   ```

---

I do not understand how 3 and 4 work, and I am not too sure what I understand about 1 and 2 is right. Below is what I understand. Please correct me where I am wrong.

I know that `0`, `1` and `2` symbolize `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

1. redirect 2 to 1, so that both of them use the same stream now (`&` escaped `1` making sure that `STDERR` does not get redirected to a file named `1` instead)
2. redirect 2 (STDERR) to null stream, so that it gets discarded
3. I do not understand this one. Shouldn't it be just

   ```
   $output = `cmd 1>/dev/null`;
   ```

   Also, if the aim is to get the `STDERR` messages at `STDOUT`, won't `1>/dev/null` redirect everything to `/dev/null`?
4. What is happening here? What is stream `3`? Is it like a temporary variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, none of this is Perl -- all of this is handled by the shell that you're invoking by using the backticks operator. So your best reading is `man sh`, or the [Shell chapter of the Unix standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_007).

In short, though, for #4:

- `3>&1`: Open FD 3 to point to where stdout currently points.
- `1>&2`: Reopen stdout to point to where stderr currently points.
- `2>&3`: Reopen stderr to point to where FD 3 currently points, which is where stdout pointed *before* the previous step was completed. Now stdout and stderr have been succesfully swapped.
- `3>&-`: Close FD 3 because it's not needed anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Though documented in the perldocs, the redirection is all standard linux redirection.  You understand 1 and 2 correctly.

3) Only STDOUT is normally caught by a basic redirect (`>`), so the original STDOUT must be discarded, *and* STDERR must be send to STDOUT.

4) `cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-` is equivalent to

```
var tmp = STDOUT;
STDOUT = STDERR;
STDERR = tmp;
delete tmp;
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally we have this:

```
1-->STDOUT
2-->STDERR
```

`2>&1` redirects file descriptor `fd2` to `fd1`

```
1-->STDOUT
   /
2./
```

`2>/dev/null` redirects `fd2` to `/dev/null`.

```
1-->STDOUT
2-->/dev/null
```

`2>&1 1>/dev/null` redirects `fd2` to `fd1`, and then redirects `fd1` to `/dev/null`

```
    /dev/null
   /
1./ STDOUT
   /
2./
```

`3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`

1. first directs a new fd 3 to wherever
   fd 1 is currently pointing (STDOUT).
2. then redirects fd1 to wherever fd2 is
   current pointing (STDERR),
3. then redirects fd 2 to wherever fd 3
   is currently pointing (STDOUT)
4. then closes fd3 (3>&- means close
   file descriptor 3).

The whole thing effectively swaps fd1 and fd2. fd3 acted as a temporary variable.

```
1 --STDOUT
 X
2 `-STDERR
```

See [the docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for more information on IO redirection.

Answer (score 1):

The redirections are evaluated from left to right. Here's a trace table:

```bash
cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

|  | 1 (stdout) | 2 (stderr) | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 |  |
| `3>&1` | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| `1>&2` | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| `2>&3` | 2 | 1* | 1 |
| `3>&-` | 2 | 1 | - |

*Notice that file descriptor 2 points to 1, not 3. This is because it points to the file descriptor that 3 points to. Because of this, 2 isn't affected when 3 is closed in the next step

As you can see, `a>&b` means "make *a* point to the thing *b* is currently pointing to"

Answer (score -2):

3.Nope. The ordering matters, so it gets rid of the original stdout, then it moves stderr to stdout.

4.`3` is just another file descriptor, same as the first 3. Most processes can use a total of 256 different file descriptors.

Comment: "2>&1 1>/dev/null" -> "... then it moves stderr to stdout". Are you sure? Doesn't it happen in the opposite order?

Comment: @Ignacio: Then how does it work in **4**? That would mean stream 3 is closed even before it was opened!

Comment: That just means that whatever *may* have been open on it has been closed.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. For `2>&3`, how can 2 point nowhere? (because whatever 3 was pointing to was just closed using `3>&-`)

Comment: FD 2 gets copied to FD 3. 2 doesn't point nowhere, 3 now points where 2 does.

Comment: @Ignacio: your understanding is wrong, please don't confuse people. From http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07: "If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the order of evaluation is from beginning to end."

Comment: And "2>&3" means that 3 is copied to 2.